# Delete list via referent ? > Was : How do you alias variable in Python ? or similar?

Tags: python, pointers, reference, alias

In Perl I can say this :

```
> perl -e '@a=(1,2,3);$b=\@a;$$b[1]=5;print @a'
153    

@a=(1,2,3);
$b=\@a;
$$b[1]=5;
print @a
```

i.e. I can change the original variable @a via the reference $b.
How can I do that in Python ?

=========

Sorry my mistake I was trying to delete the content of the referent array "a" via the reference "b".. and it does not seem to work.
What is the correct way to delete a via b

```
> a = [1,2,3]
> b = a
> b
[1, 2, 3]
> b = []
> a
[1, 2, 3]
```

'a' still not empty i.e. I have reference to variable and I want to clean it up via the reference?

Comment: Updated my answer as well to show deletion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All types in Python are references. That means you cannot re-assign an actual variable and expect it to change the original variable. However, you can certainly modify a variable through a "reference" which is automatically created on copy.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
b[0] = 0
print a
```

Output

```
[0,2,3]
```

If you want to delete a list via a reference, you can use the other solution or do the following:

```
b[:] = []
```

Comment: Isn't that just because a list is mutable? I could be completely wrong, but I don't think this works for strings/immutable objects.

Comment: @Human, You cannot change immutable objects regardless of whether you are using a new reference or an original reference, so they are outside the scope of this discussion. The question was about whether one could make a new variable that referred to the same object as an old variable. This is just a demonstration that you can.

Comment: Right, okay. I didn't mean to suggest otherwise, it was sort of a quick comment/question. Thanks.

Comment: @Human, No worries. It's good to ask for clarification when something is unclear. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can mutate a list via deletion as such:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> del b[:]
>>> b
[]
>>> a
[]
```

The special syntax `del b[:]` is equivalent to `b.__delitem__(slice(0, len(b)))` - that is, it calls a method on the object that `b` points to, which ends up mutating that object, instead of assigning a different object to `b` which is what `b = []` does.